# Vue.js: recalculate and re-render 'data' based on 'prop' change. Is this the better way to do it?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a component that has a 2 way data binding on some value from *data*. For example:

```
Vue.component ({
    data: ()=>({
        destinationValue: "1000"
    }),
    template: '<input v-model="destinationValue">'
})
```

Now, let's say this component receives a *prop* named *originValue* from which I want to calculate my *destinationValue*. If for example, the conversion ratio is equal to 2, then I can do something like this:

```
Vue.component ({
    props: ['originValue'],
    data: () => ({
        destinationValue: this.originValue* 2
    }),
    template: '<input v-model="destinationValue">'
})
```

The problem here is that, if this component receives a new value for the *originValue* prop, the value of *destinationValue* will not be updated.

I need *destinationValue* to be updateable from the < input> tag but also overwritten every time the component receives a new *originValue*.

To try and solve this, at first I tried:

```
Vue.component ({
    props: ['originValue'],
    data: ()=>({
        destinationValue: this.originValue* 2
    }),
    watch: {
        originValue: function ( val, oldVal ) {
            this.destinationValue= val * 2
        }
    }
    template: '<input v-model="destinationValue">'
})
```

But this would not work. If a new value for *originValue* is received, the  value will not be updated in the template.
This is because the imperative reassignment of *destinationValue* inside the watcher function will overwrite Vue's internal watchers on that key breaking its reactivity.

This is my workaround:

```
Vue.component ({
    props: ['originValue'],
    data: ()=>({
        destinationValue: {
            auxiliarKey: this.originValue* 2
        }
    }),
    watch: {
        originValue: function ( val, oldVal ) {
            this.destinationValue.auxiliarKey = val
        }
    }
    template: '<input v-model="destinationValue.auxiliarKey">'
})
```

What I have done here is make *destinationValue* an object with an *auxiliarKey* inside to hold the result value and then only modify that subkey in the watcher function for the *originValue* prop.
This works because Vue's internal watchers on *destinationValue* keys are preserved when my watcher's function overwrites *auxiliarKey* inside it.

I could not use a computed property because the 2way data binding (v-model) does not seem to work on computed properties, only on *data*.

Do you guys know if there is a cleaner way to do this? One that would not force me to create the *auxiliarKey* subkey?

Ty in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties).

```
Vue.component ("x-two", {
    props: ['originValue'],
    computed: {
        destinationValue(){
            return this.originValue * 2;
        }
    },
    template: '<span>{{destinationValue}}</span>'
})
```

**After your comments/edits**

As I understand it, you want to bind to your custom component using `v-model`. `v-model` is just sugar for `:value="myValue"` and `@input="myValue = $event"`. To allow your component to support v-model, just implement those two things.

```
Vue.component ("x-two", {
    props: ['originValue', 'value'],
    computed: {
        destinationValue(){
            const newValue = this.originValue * 2;
            this.$emit('input',newValue);
            return newValue;
        }
    },
    template: '<span>{{destinationValue}}</span>'
})
```

Then in your parent template:

```
<x-two :origin-value="count" v-model="calculatedCount"></x-two>
```

where `calculatedCount` is some data value on your parent.

[Working example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jBbJKj?editors=1010).

I should mention, [the very latest version of Vue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/releases/tag/v2.2.0) (as of today) added the notion of customizing the property and event `v-model` bind to, so that you could use something other than the `value` property and the `input` event.

Comment: Hello, Bert. Ty for your absolutely correct answer. I could not use a computed property though because I also need a 2way data binding on that value. I have edited my question to reflect it.

Comment: @JuanMartínMigliorini No worries. I've modified the answer as best I can with my understanding of what you are trying for. It seems like you are essentially using the component as a function. If there is no UI associated with the component and you are using the component essentially to reuse code, you may want to investigate mixins.

Comment: I checked your working example and I believe that we are not hitting the exact same point. I realized that I probably have to remake the question adding a more simple and straight working example to make my point clearer.
I really appreciate your answers, though. They have thrown light over some other aspects I was not understanding well.

Comment: @JuanMartínMigliorini In your examples in your question, you use data:{ destinationValue: 1000}. Is that a typo? In a component, your data needs to be a function that returns a data object. If I change your code to a function that returns an object, a simple watch works just fine. http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/dvMORE?editors=1010

Comment: It was indeed a typo. I edited my question accordingly. On the other hand, I checked your new code to find that, indeed, it works without the need of creating a subkey. I don't really know anymore why I came to the conclusion it did not. So I will take some more time to mess around with it. I will answer this question if I don't find anything else. Thank you very much!

Comment: @JuanMartínMigliorini Don't use an arrow function to define data. Arrow functions capture the lexical `this`, which in this case, will be the window.

Comment: Uau Bert! I really thank you for teaching me so important points. Noted.